# Request a jquery Post to issue a logout with Net Core 2.1 identity authentication

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, logout

I have a new small application that's using Net Core 2.1 identity authentication and have been running with the pre defined rows in the razor view for requesting a logout with a form:

```
<form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/Index", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm">
    <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Logout</button></li>
</form>
```

I am trying to rewrite that Post with Jquery:

```
<li><a id="LogoutBtn">Logout</a></li>



$("#LogoutBtn").click(function () {
    $.post("/Identity/Account/Logout?returnUrl=Test", function (data, status) {
        alert(status);
    });
});
```

But get the following error returned to me.

[image]

Isn't the two code snippets above doing the same thing?

The Top one is working.

Comment: I'n not intimately familiar with the asp.net core tag helpers but purely from observation, it strikes me that your jQuery implementation is not doing anything to replicate the `asp-route-returnUrl` attribute. Find out (by examining your generated HTML) what that renders on your form (e.g. an attribute, new hidden field or whatever it creates) and what effect that has on the HTTP request being sent, and then aim to reproduce that in the jQuery version. Since you're getting a "Bad Request" response, I'd expect it means that it causes a parameter to be sent, which is not being sent by jQuery

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the respons. According to https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc-6-form-tag-helper.aspx, the tag helper should generate a form element with the action attribute, so I updated the url to "/Identity/Account/Logout?returnUrl=Test" but that didn't solve the issue.

Next step would be to identify the receiving method i supose, but that seems to be easier said then done.

Comment: I never figured this one out. Instead I ended up keeping the form, but removed the Submit button since it doesn't fit in the design.
Then with some JS, I could manually control the Logout-form:

var form = document.getElementById("logoutForm");
document.getElementById("LogoutBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    form.submit();
});